# Did you know you (can/could) follow us on our Twitter?

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs

- Did you know you **could** follow us on our Twitter?

Or

- Did you know you **can** follow us on our Twitter?

Comment: Both are correct. But "... follow us **on Twitter**" is more natural. "A Twitter" is not a thing one can posess.

Comment: They are both grammatically correct, but **may** mean different things. The second says that it is possible without implying any conditions. The second says it is possible subject to an unstated condition such as "if you want to." In this case, the difference is probably meaningless, but sometimes a conditional that leaves the condition unstated is misleading. For example "if we permit it" changes the meaning materially.

Comment: The first might refer to something in the past (you could have followed us in the past), as *could* has a dual meaning as both the past of *can* and as a present-tense verb; *can* can't be past tense. In practice, both are obviously invitations to follow your Twitter stream (without any restrictions), so these nuances don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are corrrect, and in practice there is no significant difference in meaning for a US Native speaker between "Did you know that you **could** X" and "Did you know that you **can** X".

As @TypeIA points out "on Twitter" is more common than "on *our** Twitter". But I would not call either incorrect. An alternative would be "on our Twitter feed" or "on our Twitter channel." A feed or channel is associated with a particular user account as all of Twitter is not. But simply "on Twitter" is still more common, in my experience.

While the statement by @Jeff Morrow about the difference between "could" and "can" in this construction is probably technically correct, I think that in practice this distinction is rarely if ever intended, and a learner would be best to treat these as of identical meaning.

Comment: Please consider an edit in light of my comment to the OP's post.

Comment: In this context both are of identical meaning, and the speaker could use a wide range of sentences with the equivalent meaning of asking for a Twitter follow. In other contexts, *could* and *can* may mean different things. But here you could say anything from "Oi do us on Twitter huh dudes!" to "Those to whom updates might be of interest may find it informative to optionally follow our Twitter accounts." with the same meaning.